# How do I delete local remote-tracking branches when remote branch is deleted?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I deleted a branch *silver3* in Bitbucket.

I fetched changes.

However, in my local machine (Using Eclipse 4.4.2), *origin/silver3* still exists.

[image: Local]

How can I ensure that the deletion of this branch causes the deletion of my local remote-tracking branch *origin/silver3*, without having to manually delete it locally? I'd prefer to do this in Eclipse (egit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration -> Repository Settings tab.

Select the Repository.

Select  Add Entry.

Add Key "fetch.prune" and Value "true"